# Spring @transactional with @async Timeout value is not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, asynchronous, jdbc, transactions

I have created an asynchronous service for a long running stored procedure call. Things work good but the transaction is not getting timed out after the specified value given in the timeout attribute of the transactional annotation..The structure of the code is given below (not the real one...just skeleton...ignore semantics/syntax)

```
//asynchronous service
@override
@async("myCustomTaskExecutor")
@Transactional(rollbackfor=Exception.class,timeout=600)
public void serviceMethod(){
    //repository method is invoked.
    repository.callStoredProcedure();
}

//Repository method in the Repository class
@Transactional(rollbackfor=Exception.class,timeout=600)
public void callStoredProcedure(){
    //Stored procedure is called from the private method using hibernate doWork implementation.
    privateCallmethod();
}

private void privateCallmethod() throws ApplicationException{
    Session session = null;
    try{
        session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
        session.doWork(new Work(){
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                OracleCallableStatement statement =null;
                try{
                    //using hibernate 4.x and ref cursors are used...so went on with this approach..
                    //suggest if there is some better approach.
                    String sqlString =“{begin storProcName(?,?)}”;
                    statement = connection.prepareCall(sqlString);
                    statement.setInt(1,5);
                    statement.setString(2,“userName5”);
                    statement.executeUpdate();
                }
                catch(Exception e){
                    throw RunTimeException(e.getMessage);        
                }
                finally{
                    if(statement != null)
                        statement.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        throw ApplicationException(e.getMessage);        
    }
    //Not using Final block to close the session.Is it an issue ?
}
```

delay is happening in the stored procedure side(`Thread.sleep(700)` are not used) yet transaction is not timed out...

**Questions :**

1. I guess `@Transactional` is enough on the service method alone...give little bit insight on correct approach of using `@Transactional` annotation
   for this code setup.
2. Will the `@Transactional` works for the JDBC calls inside the `doWork` Interface implementation...is that whats the issue is ?
3. Some article suggest to use `oracle.jdbc.readTimeout` or `setQueryTimeout` in the `CallableStatement`... Is it the right way to achieve this.
4. Kindly point out the mistakes and explain the causes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used setQueryTimeout() approach to resolve the issue as @Transactional timeout does not work with the hibernate dowork() method...I guess its due to the hibernate work executes in different thread and it low level JDBC methods to invoke the store procedures...

NOTE: This particular application uses very spring 3.x version and hibernate 4.x with JPA 2.0 spec...little outdated versions

Answer (score 0):

If `@Transactional` Annotated method is not the entry point to the class, it will not be transactional unless you enable load time weaving (Spring default is Compile time weaving) https://stackoverflow.com/a/17698587/6785908

You should invoke `callStoredProcedure()` from outside this class, then it will be transactional. If you invoke `serviceMethod()` which in turn invokes `callStoredProcedure()`, then it will not be transactional

Comment: servicemethd() and callStoredProcedure() method are in different classes..is it what you are mentioning ?